# Populate data in specific column based on search criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to input data via userform to find a specific inventory item then find the last empty row to input the data. What's happening is the previous data is getting overwritten then the new data populates below it. Its not finding the last row of the specific column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Found As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory Log")

Lastrow = ws.Range("C:WD").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row


If Me.itemnumber.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "select item number please"
    Else
        Set Found = ws.Range("C:WD").Find(What:=Me.itemnumber.Value, _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows,_
                                                SearchDirection:=xlNext,_                                                     
                                                 MatchCase:=False)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
               MsgBox "Not found"
    Else
       For iRow = 15 To Lastrow
           ws.Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Value = Me.ponumber.Value
           ws.Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.quantity.Value
       Next iRow
    End If
End If


With ws
    .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Value = "PO#:" & "" & Me.ponumber.Value
    .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.quantity.Value
End With

End Sub
```

First entry works as should, but after second entry the previous data is overwritten then it populates into the cells that it should if its in the same column. If its a different column, the correct data populates below the first entry row and above it (see picture below).

[image]

Comment: You're always putting the data in the same rows `For iRow = 15 To Lastrow`.

Comment: Any suggestions? I've tried changing Lastrow = ws.Range(Selection, Cells(Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)).Select  and now its populating only in row 15 for all columns but overwriting all new entries.

Comment: Let's say your item is found in column 8 and lastrow=20, you are putting stuff in H15 to H20. If it's found in column 8 again and lastrow=30 you are putting stuff in H15 to H30 whereas presumably you want it go in H21 to H30?

Comment: If my item is found in column H, i want my first entry to be put in row 15 & 16. If its the same item in column H, i want my next entry to be put in 17 & 18 because it is the next blank row/cells to that column. As of now, my lastrow does not have a specific last row so it can go to row 10000 if needed (at least that's what i think).

Comment: That's my point. Your loop is always starting at 15 so will overwrite. You need to start at the first empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after playing around i finally got it to work the way i want it. Code is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Found As Range
Dim rangeheader As Range
Dim col As Long

Set rangeheader = Range("8:8")
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory Log")

With ws
    Set Found = rangeheader.Find(What:=Me.itemnumber.Value, _
                                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                   MatchCase:=False)

  If Not Found Is Nothing Then
      col = Found.Column
      Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
      For iRow = 15 To Lastrow
          If ws.Cells(iRow, col).Offset(0, 0).Value = "" Then
            ws.Cells(iRow, col).Offset(0, 0).Value = "-------"
            ws.Cells(iRow, col).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.todaysdate.Value
            ws.Cells(iRow, col).Offset(2, 0).Value = Me.ponumber.Value
            ws.Cells(iRow, col).Offset(3, 0).Value = Me.quantity.Value
          End If
      Next iRow

    Else
      MsgBox "not found"
  End If
End With

With ws
  .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(0, 0).Value = "-------"
  .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.todaysdate.Value
  .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(2, 0).Value = "PO#:" & "" & Me.ponumber.Value
  .Cells(iRow, Found.Column).Offset(3, 0).Value = Me.quantity.Value
End With

End Sub
```